# wierd problems with loops Java

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

Im just messing around with trying to create a little sorting algorithm and the first time i run the loop it doens't sort anything but the second time it creates an infinite loop and freezes

```
public void sorting(){
    int s = info.size();
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    starter();
    write.clearfile("sorted.txt");
    while (a < s){
        while (b < s);{
            b=b+1;
            sortA = info.get(a);
            sortB = info.get(b);
            if (sortB > sortA){
                info.set(a, sortB);
                info.set(b, sortA);
            }
        }
        a=a+1;
    }

    for(int x: info){
        String b = x + "";
        write.writedata(b, "sorted.txt");
    }


}
```

it runs from a second class and is initiated with a button click

Comment: `while (b < s);` that's an infinite loop all by itself right there.

Comment: remove semicolon just after `while (b < s)`. Otherwise you are running an infinite loop with empty statement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the problem:

```
while (b < s);{
```

I don't even know how your code compiled, but that line will make sure that you don't leave that while loop.

Comment: The lone semicolon counts as an empty statement. So the program just repeats doing nothing infinitely. Some IDEs can be configured to warn about empty statements.

Comment: i dont even know that really weird thank you coz ive stared at it for the last 15 minutes and not noticed that